# How to change a column value and select in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

```
name
-----
suresh
```

I want to append a value like charan to suresh and select.
I want the select query so that it should give me result as `suresh_charan`

I tried like

```
select name+'_charan' from nametable;
```

but no use.

Can I get a solution on this please.

Comment: Your query should work if there are records in nametable and there is a column name...please let me know what exactly did u get when tried above

Comment: Is this MS-TSQL? Do you get an error message? What is it?

Comment: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying + unknown at character 18 HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.                          This is the error i got

Comment: Is this MySQL or postgres? (The command will be different in each of these.)

Comment: When you asking a question please give as much as details you can in the first place and specially about the language you working on. Otherwise people waste their time.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select name||'_charan' from nametable;
```

Comment: That will also work in MySQL if that is configured to be ANSI compliant (which is something I highly recommend anyway)

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, try:

```
select concat(name, '_charan') as name_charan
from nametable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT the_column || '_charan'::text AS total_name FROM the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

For concatenation, use '+' operator....